# Получение текста из txt удалённо в Qt

Tags: html, qt, c++

Имеется txt файл на сервере. В нём - строка, являющаяся версией ПО (х.х.х).

Вопрос: каким образом, работая в Qt, получить именно эту строку в формате char/string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На удаленном компьютере должна быть некая программа, которая будет слушать определенный порт и отправлять значение версии. Варианты

1) обычный http-сервер, тогда ваш клиент должен будет запрашивать текстовый файл (как это сделано в [Http example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-http.html)) и потом читать его

2) самописный демон, примерно как в [fortune server](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-fortuneserver.html). Соответсвенно, получение информации будет как в [fortune client](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-fortuneclient.html)

Comment: А можно ли читать файл как HTML страницу, без явной скачки, и оттуда брать нужную строку?

Comment: да, я немного перемудрил. Там в примере они запрашивают данные и пишут в файл, но, конечно, эти же данные можно просто сразу использовать

Comment: @beardog, думаю, автор вопроса разберется. Делов-то, вместо `file->write(reply->readAll())` вернуть куда надо `reply->readAll()`. Это как раз QString.

Comment: @northerner Проблема в том, что я так и делал. В итоге в строке оказались иерогрифы: несколько букв Y и случайные символы (каждый раз разные)